# node red unable to connect to local MQTT broker - new rasbian install

Tags: mqtt, raspbian, node-red, mosquitto

I am setting up a [Pi Desktop](https://github.com/pi-desktop) as the basis for supporting a node red/mqtt based home automation system (looking for robustness in case of future SD failure), using the approach of retaining the 'boot' partition on the SD rather than the permanent ROM mod setting approach. I'm using the most recent version - 16 March, 2018 - of Peter Scargill's ["The Script"](https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/snippets/scargill/ekon6o/master/files/script.sh) to set up the node red/mqtt environment.

The OS image I've based the whole thing on is [raspbian-2017-07-05](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2017-07-05/).

At the point "The Script" is invoked the Pi Desktop SD->SSD cloning and the SSD partitioning have been set-up and the SD is the 'enabled' active root environment. My presumption was to make the SD environment operative with all systems prior to attempting to replicate the install on the SSD. To the best of my ability I'm attempting to ensure the root partitions on the SD & SSD are as close as possible to being identical, again for recovery purposes in case of SSD failure.

Prior to this invocation I had successfully run "The Script" on a separate SD on which Pi Desktop had not been installed.

However on the Pi Desktop SD, following completion of "The Script" install Apache & Node Red were operative but Node Red would not connect to the freshly installed local Mosquitto MQTT broker.

At line 642 "The Script" uses `sudo systemctl  start mosquitto` to start the server immediately following installation, and then `sudo systemctl enable mosquitto` to set auto mqtt start-up following reboot.

Following a reboot, if `ps -ef | grep mosq && netstat -tln | grep 1883` is invoked the result is:

```
    pi@vistacontrol:~ $ !188
    ps -ef | grep mosq && netstat -tln | grep 1883
    pi        2939  2914  0 03:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosq
    mosquit+ 10851     1  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:30 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c         /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
    tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

And attempting to configure a MQTT node in node red using the local broker IP address `127.0.0.1` results in a yellow 'Connecting' dot and no node red throughput.

After many troubleshooting attempts I finally found that if I stop the MQTT server using `sudo /etc/init.d/mosquitto stop`, re-start it using `mosquitto -d` then `ps -ef | grep mosq && netstat -tln | grep 1883` the result is:

```
    pi@vistacontrol:~ $ ps -ef | grep mosq && netstat -tln | grep 1883
    pi        3388     1  0 03:50 ?        00:00:00 mosquitto -d
    pi        3390  2914  0 03:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosq
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
    tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

If I then re-configure the MQTT node broker settings to that of the Rpi's network IP address, the node red MQTT nodes start working.

Would anyone out there be able to point to me to where & what I might look for to clarify why the difference between these two approaches. I presume any other user who attempts to apply a USB stick alternative approach to full reliance on a SD, even if not using a Pi Desktop would encounter similar difficulty.

Comment: Did you include the username and password in the initial Node-RED MQTT broker config?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly how you've configured Node-RED this is a little difficult to work out, but I'll have a guess.

The script in question sets up Mosquitto to require a username and password when connecting via the native MQTT listener (but not the websocket listener strangely).

So in order to connect with the default protocol settings in Node-RED you will need to specify a username and password (default are admin/password123).

The reason this works when you stop the mosquitto service and restarting it manually is that the service is set to point to the installed config file `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` where as when you start it manually you are not specifying the config file (mosquitto does not default to loading any config files) so you are removing the options that require username/password.

Comment: Pete Scargill's script - "the-script.sh" - includes a config option to select setting the username & password for the node-red & mosquitto install. I selected that for both the 'Pi Desktop' and the generic straight Pi3 install.

Comment: As indicated earlier, using the credentials I inserted during the script install I have no difficulty logging into the node-red control panel on both platforms, but not connecting to the mosquitto WebSocket on the 'Pi Dektop' config. No problems with the generic Pi3 install.

Comment: The question you've not answered is did you include those credentials when you configured the MQTT node.

Comment: I appear not to be explaining myself with sufficient clarity. When you refer to the mqtt node i am assuming you mean the one within the node-red control. In that case, Yes I am inserting the credentials into the mqtt broker tabs in the mqtt node in the node-red control panel. The actual tab is titled 'Security'. The credentials used are those originally inserted into the Scargill script. The setup works on an installation based on a fresh Debian Jessie install but not on an environment after the Pi Desktop s/w .

Comment: I appear not to be explaining myself with sufficient clarity. When you refer to the mqtt node i am assuming you mean the one within the node-red control panel and not something external to node-Rrd. In that case, Yes I am inserting the credentials into the mqtt broker tabs in the mqtt node in the node-red control panel. The actual tab is titled 'Security'. The credentials used are those originally inserted into the Scargill script. The setup works no problems on an installation based on a fresh Debian Jessie install but not on an environment after the Pi Desktop s/w has been installed.

Comment: Perhaps I should back track - install the Scargill script first & then set-up the Pi Desktop configuration.